# NFS client access denied

Tags: permissions, nfs, share

I created a basic NFS share on my RPi4 following the [RaspberryPi doc](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/nfs.md) and [PiMyLife tutorial](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-nfs/).

First, installed nfs-kernel

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server -y
```

then, set permissions

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /mnt/shared
sudo find /mnt/shared/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /mnt/shared/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

After that I edited the exports file

```
$ sudo nano /etc/exports
/mnt/shared/shr1 192.168.1.0/24(rw,all_squash,insecure,async,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/mnt/shared/shr2 192.168.1.0/24(ro,all_squash,insecure,async,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

Now I am able to access the share through Windows but whenever I try to copy something to it, or write anything, windows just freezes for a while and never makes the copy.

Using another rasp in the same network I was able to mount the NFS share easily, and could also write files to it.

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.1.6:/mnt/shared/shr1 /mnt/shared/
$ df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
192.168.1.6:/mnt/shared/shr1  1.8T  105G  1.6T   7% /mnt/shared
```

Are the permissions alright for Windows?

Comment: With Windows do you mean the operating system from Microsoft? I don't use it, but I don't think that it supports NFS out of the box. Can you use the NFS export on the RasPi as expected if you connect from a Linux device? What operating system, what version do you use on the RasPi? What exported directory makes problems? shr1 or shr2?

Comment: I edited the question to answer you. Please, see if thats what you mean.

Comment: @ingo: apparently Windows 10 has NFS support. It involves installing a service, some registry editing, setting-up a specific user and some more. Never tried it though.

Comment: @LjmDullaart Thanks for updating me. Seems there are some settings on MS Window$ required.

Comment: @markfree With your updated question it seems it is a problem of MS Window$. Please understand that I have voted to close the question. We cannot help much about it here.